# How to check for success in c++11 std::regex_replace?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I'd like to do the c++11 equivalent of a perl checked-replacement operation:

```
my $v = "foo.rat"

if ( $v =~ s/\.rat$/.csv/ )
{
   ...
}
```

I can do the replacement without trouble:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
   std::string s{ "foo.rat" } ;
   std::regex reg{ R"((.*)\.rat$)" } ;

   s = std::regex_replace( s, reg, "$1.csv" ) ;

   std::cout << s << std::endl ;

   s = std::regex_replace( "foo.noo", reg, "$1.csv" ) ;
   std::cout << s << std::endl ;

   return 0 ;
}
```

This gives:

```
foo.csv
foo.noo
```

Notice that the replace operation on the non-matching expression doesn't throw an error (which is what I expected).

Looking at the regex_replace documentation, it's not obvious to me how to check for the success of the replace operation.  I could do a string compare, but that seems backwards?

Comment: Just check if the old value is equal to the new value.

Comment: use `std::regex_constants::format_no_copy` on the optional param of `regex_replace()`. look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find match with `std::regex_match` or `std::regex_search`, check if something is matched, then replace found portion of string using `std::string::replace`. That shouldn't lead to performance loss.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817227/how-to-check-for-success-in-c11-stdregex-replace/35817539#35817539) that it can also be done with a [std::regex_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator). This may be handy when multiple replacements may took place.

Iterator `std::regex_iterator` repeatedly calls `std::regex_search()` until all matches are found. If the position of the iterator at the beginning and the position at the end are the same, no match was found.

Function `bool regex_replace(std::string &str, const std::string &re, const std::string& replacement)` implements this behaviour:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

bool regex_replace(std::string &str, const std::string &re, const std::string& replacement) {
    std::regex regexp(re);

    //Search regex
    std::sregex_iterator begin = std::sregex_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), regexp);
    std::sregex_iterator end = std::sregex_iterator();

    //replace using iterator
    for (std::sregex_iterator i = begin; i != end; ++i)
        str.replace(i->position(), i->length(), replacement);

    //returns true if at least one match was found and replaced
    return (begin != end);
}
```

This function operates in place. At the end `str` have the replacements. Only if any replacement was made, the function returns true.

Following code shows how to use it to make multiple replacements and detect if any was made:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {    
    std::string rgx("[0-9]");
    std::string str("0a1b2c3d4e5");
    std::string replacement("?");

    bool found = regex_replace(str, rgx, replacement);
    std::cout << "Found any: " << (found ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "string:    " << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The code substitutes every digit for the quotation mark '?':

```
Found any:  true
string:     ?a?b?c?d?e?
```

Answer (score 0):

use `std::regex_constants::format_no_copy` flag to change the behavior of `regex_replace()`. look the code below.

the return string will now be empty if match failed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
   std::string s{ "foo.rat" } ;
   std::regex reg{ R"((.*)\.rat$)" } ;
   auto rxMatchFlag = std::regex_constants::format_no_copy;  //<---use this to modify the behavior of regex_replace when matching failed.

   s = std::regex_replace( s, reg, "$1.csv", rxMatchFlag) ;
    
   if(!s.empty()) std::cout << s << std::endl ;
   else std::cout << "failed match" << std::endl;

   s = std::regex_replace( "foo.noo", reg, "$1.csv", rxMatchFlag) ; 
   if(!s.empty()) std::cout << s << std::endl ;
   else std::cout << "failed match" << std::endl;

   return 0 ;
}
```

for the other flags, look them [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_flag_type)

Answer (score -2):

I don't believe there's any direct way to find out whether any replacements were made.

(Don't confuse this with "success / not success", which is not quite the same thing.)